# Haskell / Level-order tree traversal with foldr

Tags: haskell, tree

There is a data type `Tree`, which describes my tree:

```hs
data Tree a = Leaf | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving (Eq, Show)

newtype Preorder a = PreO (Tree a) deriving (Eq, Show)
newtype Postorder a = PostO (Tree a) deriving (Eq, Show)
newtype Levelorder a = LevelO (Tree a) deriving (Eq, Show)
```

The task is: implement `in-order`, `pre-order`, `post-order` and `level-order` tree traversals with `foldr`. I have implemented all of them but `level-order` traverse is not efficient much. How can I improve it to make it faster but still with `foldr`?

The code:

```hs
instance Foldable Tree where
    foldr f ini Leaf = ini
    foldr f ini (Node left num right) = foldr f (f num (foldr f ini right)) left

instance Foldable Preorder where
    foldr f ini (PreO Leaf) = ini
    foldr f ini (PreO (Node left num right)) = f num (foldr f (foldr f ini (PreO right)) (PreO left))

instance Foldable Postorder where
    foldr f ini (PostO Leaf) = ini
    foldr f ini (PostO (Node left num right)) = foldr f (foldr f (f num ini) (PostO right)) (PostO left)

instance Foldable Levelorder where
    foldr f ini (LevelO Leaf) = ini
    foldr f ini (LevelO tree@(Node left num right)) = helper [tree]
        where
            helper [] = ini
            helper (Leaf : xs) = helper xs
            helper ((Node left num right) : xs) = f num (helper (xs ++ [left, right]))
```

Comment: You could try this alternative: add an argument and write `helper xs rest` instead. Initially, `rest=[]`. When you recurse, instead of `helper (xs++[left,right])` use `helper xs (right:left:rest)`. Then let `helper [] rest = helper (reverse rest) []` for non-empty `rest`. I am unsure if this will actually be faster, but one can try and see.

Comment: If that actually improved performance, you could post it as an answer. Answering one's own question is perfectly OK here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```hs
instance Foldable Levelorder where
    foldr f ini (LevelO Nil) = ini
    foldr f ini (LevelO tree@(Branch left num right)) = helper [tree] []
        where
            helper [] rest
                | null rest = ini
                | otherwise = helper (reverse rest) []
            helper (Nil : xs) rest = helper xs rest
            helper ((Branch left num right) : xs) rest = f num (helper xs (right:left:rest))
```